# Joining an aggregation with the expected permutations

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an aggregated table `t_base` grouped by three fields (date and two keys) and the count of how many times this pair of keys happen in that date

| date | R_id | Q_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1/4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1/5 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 1/5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

And another table `t_comb` with all possible co-occurrences of the two keys

| R_id | Q_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

How can I join them, filling the day a given `R_id` happens with all possible `Q_ids`, with a count of zero? Resulting in the following (order does not matter, of course):

Alternative wording: every time a R_id happens in a day, I also need all other Q_ids that can pair with that R_id to be added in that same day

| date | R_id | Q_id | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1/4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1/4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1/5 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 1/5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1/5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/5 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1/5 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

I've tried many permutations of joining the tables with left/outer joins on the R_id field, but can't quite get the correct result.

Sample code to be toyed with (using integers as dates):

```sql
with
t_base(d, r_id, q_id, c) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 1, 2, 2),
        (1, 1, 3, 4),
        (2, 2, 2, 5),
        (2, 1, 1, 1)
)
, t_comb(r_id, q_id) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 1),
        (1, 2),
        (1, 3),
        (2, 1),
        (2, 2)
)
select ???
```

My actual t_base has almost 1.4 billion records, so I'd rather go for performance over readability here, if possible.

It is guaranteed that (date, R_id, Q_id) is unique in t_base, as well as (R_id, Q_id) in t_comb. It is also guaranteed that all t_base.r_id exists in t_comb.r_id (but not the opposite, if possible - I could make it happen).

If a pair of (date, r_id) does not happen in t_base, it should not happen in the result either.

Comment: I have no idea how to title this, but I hope the question body is clear enough. Edits are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```sql
with
    dist_r as (
        select distinct
            d,
            r_id
        from
            t_base
    ),
    all_q as (
        select
            dist_r.d,
            dist_r.r_id,
            t_comb.q_id
        from
            dist_r
            join t_comb on (t_comb.r_id = dist_r.r_id)
    )
select
    all_q.d,
    all_q.r_id,
    all_q.q_id,
    nvl (t_base.c, 0)
from
    all_q
    left join t_base on (
        all_q.r_id = t_base.r_id
        and all_q.q_id = t_base.q_id
        and all_q.d = t_base.d
    )
```

1. Calculate all distinct pairs of `date` and `r_id`
2. Calculate all possible trios `date`, `r_id`, `q_id`
3. Query original data, if null replace with 0

Comment: This doesn't quite match the desired output. Some of the records which should've been count=0 are using the count from a different day

Comment: @Mephy, my mistake: forgot join clause on date. Corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try example

```
select tr.d,tr.r_id,c.q_id,coalesce(t.c,0) cnt
from (select d,r_id from t_base group by d,r_id) as tr 
left join t_comb c on tr.r_id=c.r_id
left join  t_base t on tr.d=t.d and c.r_id=t.r_id and c.q_id=t.q_id
order by tr.d ,tr.r_id,c.q_id
```

It is interesting check query on base with 1.4 billion records.